# Javascript Chrome confirm box delay

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When displaying a confirm box in javascript, there seems to be a delay after clicking Yes or No when the Yes or No causes a page redirect. The delay is about the duration of how long the confirm box is open for. This only happens in Chrome for me. Does anyone have a solution to make this so there is no delay in Chrome?

A simple example depicting the problem:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var goToGoogle = confirm("Go to Google?");
            if (goToGoogle) {
                window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm seeing no delay in `19.0.1084.1 dev`. It may be a bug that is fixed in a later version.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98275

Comment: Let us assume that clients may be using a version of Chrome which has this bug. Is there a way I can effectively rewrite the above code which would "work around" the bug? Basically depending if the user clicks Yes, or No, then redirect to a different location.

Comment: You could build your own modal instead of using the confirm.

Comment: @lots_of_questions: See my improved answer below- I've added a potential work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be [Issue 98275: Javascript confirm dialog creates long delay and appears to lock up page](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98275). It is marked as fixed, though it seems users are still seeing it based on the comments. I can confirm the bug is present in `18.0.1025.142`.

As for a solution for users with versions of Chrome without this bug fix, I've created a basic implementation of a modal dialog you can use [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saMuH/). It is based on this article: [Create a Modal Dialog Using CSS and Javascript](http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/).

Alternatively, if you are using/plan to use jQuery, you could use [jQuery dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).